# How to convert pointcloud2 to separate depth and rgb image messages

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wanting to convert a filtered pointcloud2 message into separate depth and rgb image messages.  RGBDSLAM requires an input of a RBG image topic as well as a depth image topic.  I have tried to just pass in the filtered pointcloud2 message into "config/topic_points", but no frames are captured. Any ideas?

System: Ubuntu, Fuerte, Precise

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56007/how-to-convert-pointcloud2-to-separate-depth-and-rgb-image-messages/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-02-22**:
RGBDSLAM requires "sensor_msgs:Image" whereas my filtered message is "sensor_msgs:Pointcloud2".  Looks as though I will have to break my filter into two parts: one for depth, one for rgbd so I can publish two separate filtered image messages.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-22**:
Was this comment meant for my post? If so, you can also acquire depth and rgb images separately, which sounds exactly like what you need.

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-02-22**:
Yes, I realized I should break up the filter.  I think I might run into pcl issues involving fromROSmsg() because I am trying to grab the data from a sensor_msg::Image and not a sensor_msg::Pointcloud2.  I'll make those changes and post an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you are using a Kinect, so then my question is why you would want to convert this? Originally the images received from the Kinect are depth images and RGB images already, the two are just combined to form a pointcloud with RGB data in one matrix. Splitting combined images seems a bit redundant then

In other words, I would advice you to retrieve RGB and depth images instead, from their own respective frames.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2